# Not able to read content in the child node of XML file using JAXB using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

1. When I tried to use the code below wont able to read the value inside SupervisoryOrg which is child of File. Getting the Output as null ever where. Need to get the values of SupervisoryOrg. So need to read each child node with respect to one parent node.
2. And need to validate common `SuperiorOrgRefID` value with respect to `OrgRefID`.

```
Actual O/P->
    FileContent{OrgRefID='null', OrgName='null', EffectiveDate='null', AvailabilityDate='null', SuperiorOrgRefID='null', OrgSubType='null', PrimaryBusSite='null', InactivationDate='null', Operation='null'}  

    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
  <!--The sample values are based on the prototype1 Workday tenant.
    The supervisory org ID structure will be the position hierarchy structure in SuccessFactors-->
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30001923</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>A/R Supervisor</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30004384</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30008348</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>ABC</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>2020-05-12</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>2020-05-12</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID />
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000067</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30004335</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Access and Scheduling Coordinator - CARCIP</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30004375</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000016</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30000031</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Administrator</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30005414</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000078</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30000544</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Administrator</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30007640</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000022</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30000776</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Administrator</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30002745</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000031</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30001933</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Administrator</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30002745</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000031</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30001302</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001005</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000039</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30001528</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001527</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000094</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30001542</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001529</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000094</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30001868</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001103</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30002334</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001103</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30002563</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>2020-01-24</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>2020-01-24</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001529</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000052</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30004576</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30003375</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000081</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30005394</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30005375</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000073</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30005628</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001103</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30006515</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30001103</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30006541</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30000361</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30008222</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>2019-10-15</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>2019-10-15</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30000361</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <SupervisoryOrg>
    <OrgRefID>30004575</OrgRefID>
    <OrgName>Account Executive Business Solutions</OrgName>
    <EffectiveDate>1900-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <AvailabilityDate>1900-01-01</AvailabilityDate>
    <SuperiorOrgRefID>30000361</SuperiorOrgRefID>
    <OrgSubType>Position</OrgSubType>
    <PrimaryBusSite>60000054</PrimaryBusSite>
    <InactivationDate>9999-12-31</InactivationDate>
    <OrgIDforSubordinates />
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
  </SupervisoryOrg>
  <RecordCount>20</RecordCount>
</File>
            
            import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
            
            @XmlRootElement(name = "File")
            public class FileContent {
                private String OrgRefID;
                private String OrgName;
                private String EffectiveDate;
                private String AvailabilityDate;
                private String SuperiorOrgRefID;
                private String OrgSubType;
                private String PrimaryBusSite;
                private String InactivationDate;
                private String Operation;
            
                public FileContent() {
                }
            
                public String getOrgRefID() {
                    return OrgRefID;
                }
            
                public void setOrgRefID(String orgRefID) {
                    OrgRefID = orgRefID;
                }
            
                public String getOrgName() {
                    return OrgName;
                }
            
                public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
                    OrgName = orgName;
                }
            
                public String getEffectiveDate() {
                    return EffectiveDate;
                }
            
                public void setEffectiveDate(String effectiveDate) {
                    EffectiveDate = effectiveDate;
                }
            
                public String getAvailabilityDate() {
                    return AvailabilityDate;
                }
            
                public void setAvailabilityDate(String availabilityDate) {
                    AvailabilityDate = availabilityDate;
                }
            
                public String getSuperiorOrgRefID() {
                    return SuperiorOrgRefID;
                }
            
                public void setSuperiorOrgRefID(String superiorOrgRefID) {
                    SuperiorOrgRefID = superiorOrgRefID;
                }
            
                public String getOrgSubType() {
                    return OrgSubType;
                }
            
                public void setOrgSubType(String orgSubType) {
                    OrgSubType = orgSubType;
                }
            
                public String getPrimaryBusSite() {
                    return PrimaryBusSite;
                }
            
                public void setPrimaryBusSite(String primaryBusSite) {
                    PrimaryBusSite = primaryBusSite;
                }
            
                public String getInactivationDate() {
                    return InactivationDate;
                }
            
                public void setInactivationDate(String inactivationDate) {
                    InactivationDate = inactivationDate;
                }
            
                public String getOperation() {
                    return Operation;
                }
            
                public void setOperation(String operation) {
                    Operation = operation;
                }
            
                public FileContent(String orgRefID, String orgName, String effectiveDate, String availabilityDate, String superiorOrgRefID, String orgSubType, String primaryBusSite, String inactivationDate, String operation) {
                    OrgRefID = orgRefID;
                    OrgName = orgName;
                    EffectiveDate = effectiveDate;
                    AvailabilityDate = availabilityDate;
                    SuperiorOrgRefID = superiorOrgRefID;
                    OrgSubType = orgSubType;
                    PrimaryBusSite = primaryBusSite;
                    InactivationDate = inactivationDate;
                    Operation = operation;
                }
            
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "FileContent{" +
                            "OrgRefID='" + OrgRefID + '\'' +
                            ", OrgName='" + OrgName + '\'' +
                            ", EffectiveDate='" + EffectiveDate + '\'' +
                            ", AvailabilityDate='" + AvailabilityDate + '\'' +
                            ", SuperiorOrgRefID='" + SuperiorOrgRefID + '\'' +
                            ", OrgSubType='" + OrgSubType + '\'' +
                            ", PrimaryBusSite='" + PrimaryBusSite + '\'' +
                            ", InactivationDate='" + InactivationDate + '\'' +
                            ", Operation='" + Operation + '\'' +
                            '}';
                }
            }
            
            import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
            import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
            import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
            import java.io.File;
            
            public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                FileContent fileContent  = XMLtoPersonExample("Demo1.xml");
                        System.out.println(fileContent);
                        personToXMLExample(fileContent);
                        System.out.println(fileContent);
                    }
                    private static FileContent XMLtoPersonExample(String filename) throws Exception {
                        File file = new File(filename);
                        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FileContent.class);
                        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                        return (FileContent) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                    }
            
                    private static void personToXMLExample(FileContent fileContent) throws Exception {
                        File file = new File("WritingFile.xml");
                        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FileContent.class);
                        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(fileContent, file);
                        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(fileContent, System.out);
                    }
            
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the information is surrounded by `<SupervisoryOrg></SupervisoryOrg>` tags. The `File` tag can only directly access the `SupervisoryOrg` tags and the `RecordCount` tag. To access the information you need, you have to get the information from the `SupervisoryOrg` tags, not from the `File` tag.

Comment: How to read the data of under <SupervisoryOrg> tag?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used the library you use.